# How to import word document in excel keeping the same formatting style?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to generate a Ms Word documents with VBA using a template.
I need to import the Ms Word template it into excel (in a Sheet), manipulate it (by adding some data from other excel sheets) and then generate the word document.
The problem is that I'm not able to copy the template in excel, it contains some tables and text, and when I try to copy/paste it doesn't keep the same formatting style ... I tried to use the Paste Option as mentionned [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-a-word-table-into-excel-HP010254130.aspx) but it doesn't solve the problem ...

Should I manipulate the template programatically with VBA and fill it directly from excel ?

Comment: Yes to the second option - that's going to work much better.

Comment: The problem is that the template contains some complex tables (nested) and i didn't even find a way to get the tables/cells/rows ID/INDEX ...
that's why i thought to import the word doc into excel ...

Comment: Quick google gives:  http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=33517

Comment: Thanks i already found that :p but still insufficient ... i really have many nested tables and i don't want to lose my time counting them ... and the code will not be generic if we made some changes in the template ...

Comment: Have you looked into using bookmarks for this?  Eg: `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("blah").Range.InsertAfter "Your text here"`

Comment: Your idea was really great, i was looking how to use Bookmarks, the problem is that when i added some of them in the template i'm not able to manipulate them from VBA ! When i try to access a BookMarked area to change text for example :
`ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("test")`
I got a Run-Time Error '5941' :
The requested memeber of the collection does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I implemented [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) solution :
I copy the template, rename i, and fill it using the bookmarks I already defined :

```
    With myDoc.Bookmarks
       .Item("myBookmarkItem").Range.Text = "New Text"
    End With
```